# Copying or moving a Hierarchy of Folders & MOUNTPOINTS in Windows

Tags: windows

I have a Folder that contains a hierarchy of folders and mountpoints (plus a few other files):

[image: Screenshot]

How do I COPY this folder including everything in it but EXCLUDING the contents of the mounted drives? (If I attempt to copy the entire folder, it also tries to copy the contents of each and every mounted drive.)

xcopy, as suggested by @John unfortunately does not work:
I tried "xcopy I:\MP_T7_Drives B:\EDNA-I\MP_T7_Drives /T /E" but this command actually creates (or tries to create) the entire folder hierarchy in the destination folder.
The "I:\MP_T7_Drives" Folder contains a sub-folder "I:\MP_T7_Drives\MP_T7_01_Drive" and this subfolder is a mountpoint that points to a physical device i.e. a T7 SSD drive.
So: When copying "I:\MP_T7_Drives", the "I:\MP_T7_Drives\MP_T7_01_Drive" subfolder should be created and it should only contain a mountpoint. It should not contain actual "real" subfolders.
(Also, I received an "insufficient memory" error which, apparently, may occur if running xcopy to copy a file or folder whose filename path is greater than 255 characters. Since the xcopy command tries to copy the entire hierarchy rather than stopping at the mountpoint, this is not surprising)

Comment: Does this help:    xcopy “C:\Top level folder” “D:\Top level folder” /T /E ?   This copies folder structure.   Test first.

Answer (score 0):

FastCopy (available from https://fastcopy.jp/) seems to be able to do what I am after.
It has an option [Option, Main Settings, Copy Options] "Copy Junction/Symlink as Junction/Symlink (not target)" With that option checked, it will only copy the link rather than the target of the link.